# SpeechSynthesis.cancel() throws an error on desktop safari

Tags: javascript, safari, text-to-speech, web-audio-api

Using SpeechSynthesis api on safari, cancelling a speech using `SpeechSynthesis.cancel()` throws an error on desktop safari (13.0.3)

press play and then cancel button to see the error being thrown in the console

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in safari, but how do you go about starting a new speech without using cancel() first, any workarounds?

code snippet below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="resume">Resume</button>
<button id="cancel">Cancel</button>

<div id="data"></div>

<script>
  const play = document.getElementById("play");
  const pause = document.getElementById("pause");
  const resume = document.getElementById("resume");
  const cancel = document.getElementById("cancel");

  function speakAnew(){
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    utterance.text = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15"
    utterance.lang = "en-US";

    utterance.onpause = (event) => {
      console.log('onpause: ', event)
    }

    utterance.onend = (event) => {
      console.log('onend: ', event)
    }

    utterance.onerror = (event) => {
      console.error('error: ', event)
    }

    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance)
  }

  play.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("data").innerText = "play";
    speakAnew()
  });

  pause.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("data").innerText = "pause";

    speechSynthesis.pause();
  });

  resume.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("data").innerText = "resume";
    speechSynthesis.resume();
  });

  cancel.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("data").innerText = "cancel";
    speechSynthesis.cancel();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: @Frazer just throws an error, the error field itself is empty

Comment: Is it from line 36? Does the speech stop?

Comment: Turns out this is the correct behaviour and it's all the other browsers that have the problem! https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#speechsynthesiserrorevent-attributes - see second error code "interrupted".

Comment: @Frazer you are right but then how do you go about starting a new speech. I couldn't find a way to start a new speech in safari, It won't any audio after that

Comment: Is the problem now that when Cancel is pressed the Play button doesn't work? Any more information?

Comment: @Frazer exactly, after you cancel an already playing speech, the error is shown, then you can't play any speech after that by pressing play

Comment: I went to an Apple shop and used their laptops to test this. There was no problem either with your code on a server not running it through the 'Run code snippet' button. If you find out whet the problem is please let me know.

Comment: @Frazer wow, you didn't have to do that, thank you so much. Unfortunately I can reproduce it consistently on an all 13.x.x and 12.x.x versions of safari both on an iphone and mac. The work around that I created is to start a speech with setTimeout, ```window.setTimeout(() => window.speechSynthesis.speak(synth), 0)```

Comment: hey @Frazer! I'm facing a similar issue. I'm not sure I understood where you applied your workaround. Can you please elaborate or maybe update your snippet with the workaround? Thank you

Comment: @GeorgeEracleous you should address your question to David as it was his workaround.